# Increment in ternary operator Java

Tags: java, increment, ternary-operator

I'm writing small program, and want to get access to an element in array with the loop. And I need to increment "array index" variable for next iteration.

Here is the code:

```
winner[turn] = subField[(int)Math.floor(i / 10.0)][i % 10].equalsIgnoreCase("O") ? false : winner[turn];
turn++;
```

Is it possible to make one line of code from it?

PS: I'm trying to write less lines only for myself. It's a training for brain and logic.

Comment: It's already unreadable on two lines. Making it in one line will only make things worse.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be one line of code? It's usually best to make your source code as easily readable as possible. If you're hoping that speed will be faster with the one line, consider the fact that the compiler may optimize your more-easily-read form of the code into something fast anyway, or that the speed increase will be extremely minimal at best.

Comment: just trying to write small game with minimum lines of code). I know, it would be awful to read it. It's just like achievement for myself. "I did it".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf :) It's a fine game as long as you don't do it in any "real" code! For future reference, if you've got a question that's just for the intellectual challenge and not for production code, you should probably mention that in the question; otherwise people will probably assume you're a newb trying to do something they shouldn't do. :)

Comment: Can you define a line of code? Are you simply trying to reduce the total number of semi colons in your source code? Java reads \n characters as spaces, so you can actually put your whole source on a single line if you want

Comment: Well, next time I'll say it in question). Writing everythig in one line - is sort of cheating. I have line-breaks after semicolons, after loops and if-statements. Reducing number of lines is about doing multiple things in a single line.

Comment: @NonGrate line break after open/close braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it can be done for sure:

```
winner[turn] = subField[(int)Math.floor(i / 10.0)][i % 10].
                              equalsIgnoreCase("O") ^ winner[turn++];
```

Look that there is not even ternary operator there.

But not because it is shorter it is better (and certainly not clearer). So I'd recommend you do it in these many lines:

```
String aSubField = subField[(int)Math.floor(i / 10.0)][i % 10];
if (aSubField.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
    winner[turn] = false;
turn++;
```

Look, even there is no need to assign the value in case the comparison yields `false`.

[edit]

YAY! Just found my XOR was wrong ... that's just the problem with golf, it tooks a lot of time to figure it is wrong .... (in this case, if the cond is true but the previous value is false, it won't work).

So let me golf it other way :)

```
winner[turn] = !subField[i/10][i%10].equalsIgnoreCase("O") & winner[turn++];
```

Note the ! and the &

[edit]

Thanks to @Javier for giving me an even more compact and confuse version :) this one:

```
winner[turn++] &= !subField[i/10][i%10].equalsIgnoreCase("O");
```

Comment: +1. This is better golfing than my answer, since it replaces the ternary operator -- which is basically three expressions smushed into one -- with a simple operator. Bonus points for using xor, which you generally don't get to see outside of randomization (including hashes, etc), compression or golf. :)

Comment: you can replace `(int)Math.floor(i / 10.0)` with `i / 10`

Comment: @Javier holy cow. How did EVERYONE miss that. However if i is a floating point type already then this doesn't exactly work. Furthermore, if you're naming floating point values i, then we have even more problems :)

Comment: Should `&&` be `&`? This looks like it would only increment if the first part of the expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @Javier. I've included that also

Comment: @Cruncher if he's using a double, then he needs to convert it to (int) in the remainder operation.

Comment: What you have is fine, but for the record `&` works just fine with booleans. It's basically like `&&` but without short-circuiting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Comment: @Javier `float % int` is legal in java. However it will produce a float which is not a valid index, so yeah, i has to be an int.

Comment: Thanks @yshavit I have changed && to &. Didn't know & don't do short-circuit

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down a bit. What you have is:

```
winner[turn] = (some condition) ? false : (expression involving turn)
(increment turn)
```

Well, why not increment turn in the array access? That means it'll be incremented by the time you evaluate expressions on the right hand side, but you can easily adjust it back to its previous value as needed.

```
winner[turn++] = (some condition) ? false : (expression involving (turn - 1) )
```

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment. Using `++` multiple times(or even just `++` and another reference to the variable like in this case) in the same statement can be super confusing, and all depends on evaluation order. I would shoot anyone who wrote this in production code lol

Comment: Yeah, I deleted mine after I saw you deleted yours. :) I definitely agree about it. The only time I ever use it "inline" like that is in `for` loops. Any time else, I consider the increment operation to be logically separate from whatever else, and I'll separate them even if it's pretty trivial. The "separation of concerns" principle applies to each line just as much as it applies to each class.

Comment: In the case of a for loop, the "step" is really considered a line of code on it's own. It's hardly "inline", as can be easily seen if you expand it to a while loop.

Comment: Yeah, I meant conceptually -- I'm speaking loosely here. Basically, the whole `for(...)` is one construct in my head: "loop on the variable." Anywhere else, "use the variable" and "increment the variable" are conceptually separate for me. Again, this is according to loosey-goosey feelings, not anything formal like the JLS, equivalent bytecode, etc.

Comment: `winner[turn++] = subField[i / 10][i % 10].equalsIgnoreCase("O") ? false : winner[turn-1];`